# Map from list of strings to list of enums with automapper

Tags: c#, enums, automapper

I have class Model and class ModelDto:

```
class Model
{
    public List<string> ValuesList { get; set; }   
    ...
}

class ModelDto
{
    public List<MyEnumDto> MyEnumList { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I am ussing automapper I would like to know how to Map from the list of strings to a list of enums.

To map a single value I have something like this:

```
public static MyEnumDto MapMyEnum(string value)
{
    Enum.TryParse(value, out MyEnumDto myEnumDto);
    return myEnumDto;
}
```

And it works when I use it like:

```
CreateMap<Model, ModelDto>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.MyEnum, opt => opt.MapFrom(origin => MapMyEnum(origin.value)))
```

But I do know how to extend this approach when I deal with a List. Any suggestion?

Comment: You don't need `TryParse`, `string` to `enum` is a built-in conversion. See also https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html.

Answer (score 2):

If `MyEnumDto` is an `enum`. The below mapping is enough to convert list of `string` to list of `enum`

```
CreateMap<Model, ModelDto>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.MyEnumList, opt => opt.MapFrom(origin => origin.ValuesList))
```

Comment: And the `MapFrom` is needed only when the names are not the same.